# Quotients rewritten as a sum and solved for.

Tags: analysis

So I thought about why we divide polynomials and stop once we reached a certain point, which we simply stop at and say "That's the remainder and we don't really need to do much else."

Pretty much:

Edit: Sorry for a few mistakes.

$\frac{x^2+2x+2}{x+1}=x+1+\frac{1}{x+1}$

...and then I decided to go further.

$x+1+\frac{1}{x+1}=x+1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^4}+$...$=x+1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(x^{-1})^{n}$

$=x+1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x^{-1})^{2n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x^{-1})^{2n}$

$=x+1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x^{-1})^{2n}}{x^{-1}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x^{-1})^{2n}$

$=x+1+\frac{1}{x^{-1}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(x^{-1})^{2n}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x^{-1})^{2n}$

$=x+1+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(x^{-1})^{2n}}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x^{-1})^{2n}$

$=x+1+(x-1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(x^{-1})^{2n}}$

$\frac{x^2+2x+2}{x+1}=x+1+[x-1]\frac{1-(x^{-2})^{\infty+1}}{1-x^{-2}}-1$

So... I believe I can do this with other polynomials being divided, but why don't we do stuff like this?  Also, if anybody could simplify the last equation so that both sides look the same, go right ahead.  I also noticed that my solution tends to be wrong for $-1<x<1$ because of the $\infty$ in the exponent.  I wonder if it still holds true if you solved even further if someone could do that for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Your first line isn't correct. $\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x+1}$ has no remainder. I imagine you meant $\frac{x^2+2x+2}{x+1}$ but it is unclear.

Answer: What you have constructed is a power series expansion for $\frac{1}{1+x}$. These have uses but as you have noticed for the values $-1<x<1$ consecutive terms makes the expression fluctuate and it is unstable. With a truly infinity amount of terms it will work but obviously this isn't doable.

You last line includes the expression $\left(x^{-2}\right)^{\infty+1}$ which is a poor expression as infinity is not a number and shouldn't be treated as one. You should have considered the limit of the sum:
$$\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^{-2}(1-x^{-2i})}{1-x^{-2}}=\frac{x^{-2}}{1-x^{-2}}=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$$
Then noticed that:

$$[x-1]\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{x+1}$$

which is what you started with.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into power series.